# How to fix error in procedure SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

there is a hranimka, when it was created, an error occurs. Maybe she who struck by the ...

**The stored procedure:**

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE insert_log(

  IN LogType INT, 
  IN LogIdNote INT,
  IN LogName VARCHAR, 
  IN LogTime TIMESTAMP, 
  IN logTypeCategory INT, 
  IN LogIdUser INT) 

begin

INSERT INTO log (LogType, 
                 LogIdNote, 
                 LogName, 
                 LogTime, 
                 logTypeCategory, 
                 LogIdUser, 
                 LogTypeUser, 
                 LogUrl)
SELECT LogType, LogIdNote, LogName, LogTime, logTypeCategory, LogIdUser, url.URLCategorysubscribetotype, u.UsersTypeAccount FROM users u LEFT JOIN categorysubscribetotype url ON url.CategoryTypeCategorysubscribetotype = LogType WHERE u.idUsers = LogIdUser;

end //
```

**Error:**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INT LogType, INT LogIdNote, VARCHAR LogName, TIMESTAMP LogTime,
>   I' at line 3

I tried only change data types at params.

I think, the next code will give me a good result, but I need save result from SELECT query at variable and insert it at query Insert:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_log(

  IN pLogType INT, 
  IN pLogIdNote INT,
  IN pLogName VARCHAR(150), 
  IN pLogTime TIMESTAMP, 
  IN plogTypeCategory INT, 
  IN pLogIdUser INT) 

BEGIN

DECLARE user_type INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE url VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT;

SET user_type = (SELECT UsersTypeAccount FROM users WHERE idUsers = pLogIdUser);
SET url = (SELECT URLCategorysubscribetotype FROM categorysubscribetotype WHERE CategoryTypeCategorysubscribetotype = pLogType);

INSERT INTO log (pLogType, 
                 pLogIdNote, 
                 pLogName, 
                 pLogTime, 
                 plogTypeCategory, 
                 pLogIdUser, 
                 pLogTypeUser, 
                 pLogUrl)
VALUES (
                 LogType, 
                 LogIdNote, 
                 LogName, 
                 LogTime, 
                 logTypeCategory, 
                 LogIdUser, 
                 user_type, 
                 url
);

END |

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Refer to the documentation first: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html Pay special attention to procedure parameters: `proc_parameter: [ IN | OUT | INOUT ] param_name type`

Comment: And then read the documentation on datatype specifications.

Comment: Look please at question, I added **IN** param. There is error too

Comment: Please don't edit away the error in the original question, it makes @David's answer make no sense. If you've modified your code, post it as a update at the end, instead of replacing the original. And show the new error message -- in a comment below you said it's now on line 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
INSERT INTO log (pLogType, //wrong!
                 pLogIdNote, 
                 pLogName, 
                 pLogTime, 
                 plogTypeCategory, 
                 pLogIdUser, 
                 pLogTypeUser, 
                 pLogUrl)
```

You have used the parameter as column while they should be `VALUES` try this Query

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE insert_log(
    IN pLogType INT, 
    IN pLogIdNote INT,
    IN pLogName VARCHAR(150), 
    IN pLogTime TIMESTAMP, 
    IN plogTypeCategory INT, 
    IN pLogIdUser INT) 

   BEGIN

    DECLARE user_type INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE url VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT;

    SET user_type = (
                        SELECT UsersTypeAccount 
                        FROM users 
                        WHERE idUsers = pLogIdUser
                    );
    SET url = (
                        SELECT URLCategorysubscribetotype 
                        FROM categorysubscribetotype 
                        WHERE CategoryTypeCategorysubscribetotype = pLogType
               );

    INSERT INTO log (
                     `LogType`, 
                     `LogIdNote`, 
                     `LogName`, 
                     `LogTime`, 
                     `logTypeCategory`, 
                     `LogIdUser`, 
                     `LogIdUserType`, /*I added this*/
                     `LogIdUrl`,     /*this one too */
    )VALUES (
                     pLogType, 
                     pLogIdNote, 
                     pLogName, 
                     pLogTime, 
                     plogTypeCategory,  
                     pLogIdUser,
                     user_type, 
                     url
    );

   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Please note You need to adjust this stored procedure, there was few mistakes. for example `pLogTypeUser` and `pLogUrl` are undefined and I added comments where you need to change the column name.

Answer (score 0):

[Your syntax is wrong](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).  The data types come after the parameter names, the `IN`/`OUT` specifiers come before.  Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_log(

  IN LogType INT, 
  IN LogIdNote INT,
  IN LogName VARCHAR(10), 
  IN LogTime TIMESTAMP, 
  IN logTypeCategory INT, 
  IN LogIdUser INT)

begin

...
```

**Edit:** Also note that I added a size specifier to the `VARCHAR` data type, since [it requires one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html).  I guessed at `10`, but you can replace that value with whatever yours is.

Comment: Sure, but now after editing procedure, I get also error at line 5. I edited question

Comment: `VARCHAR` requires a size, e.g. `VARCHAR(16)`

Comment: @Elhan: *What* is the error?  *Which line* is 5?  Maybe the data types like `VARCHAR` need additional specifiers?  What does the documentation say?

Comment: At document tells that use standart data types, it also be **CHAR** instead VARCHAR

Comment: @Elhan: If you need to use `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` then use `CHAR`.  The original question used `VARCHAR` so I just assumed that to be the intended data type.  (Note also that I've updated the answer to correct the second issue.)

Comment: I added VARCHAR(150), now error at line 20. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 20

Comment: @Elhan: Then it sounds like you have an error on line 20.  Am I supposed to just guess what line 20 is?  I can't help with code you don't show.  It's probably just another syntax error, and you should probably again just check the documentation.

Comment: I extended my question with a some example